# Magento table CSS issue - Paypal Order Review page

Tags: magento-1.7, paypal-express

I have a highly screwed up template file which uses tables to display order totals, quantity and grand totals... the template is paypal/express/review/details.phtml

I wanted to ask if anyone knows of a way I could get the layout to display the items in their correct positions? This has had me stuck for nearly two hours and although its a relatively simple task its had me banging my head of of the desk!!!

```
<table id="details-table" class="data-table">
    <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): $colspan = $rowspan = 2; else: $colspan = $rowspan = 1; endif; ?>
    <col />
    <col width="1" />
    <col width="1" />
    <col width="1" />
    <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
    <col width="1" />
    <col width="1" />
    <?php endif; ?>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="<?php echo $rowspan ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Product Name') ?></th>
            <th colspan="<?php echo $colspan ?>" class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Price') ?></th>
            <th rowspan="<?php echo $rowspan ?>" class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?></th>
            <th colspan="<?php echo $colspan ?>" class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Subtotal') ?></th>
        </tr>
        <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
            <tr>
                <th class="a-right"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(false) ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(true) ?></th>
                <th class="a-right"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(false) ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(true) ?></th>
            </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </thead>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('totals'); ?>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
            <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('details-table');</script>
```

Anyone able to assist?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redesigned it with CSS instead of Tables...

```
<div class="cart-div-title">
                    <div class="cart-div--title-inner">
                        <div class="head-item"><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Item') ?></span></div>
                        <div class="head-price a-center"><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Full Price') ?></span></div>
                        <div class="head-qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?></div>
                        <div class="head-total"><?php echo $this->__('Total') ?></div>
                    </div>
                    <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
                    <div>
                        <div class="a-right"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(false) ?></div>
                        <div><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(true) ?></div>
                        <div class="a-right"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(false) ?></div>
                        <div><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(true) ?></div>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>

    <div class="fieldset-div">
        <fieldset>
            <div id="details-table" class="data-table">
                <col width="2" />
                <col />
                <col width="2" />
                <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
                <col width="2" />
                <?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(false) ?>
                <col width="2" />
                <?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(true) ?>
                <col width="2" />
                <?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(false) ?>
                <col width="2" />
                <?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(true) ?>
                <col width="2" />

        <?php endif; ?>
            <?php $mergedCells = ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices() ? 2 : 1); ?>       
               <?php $i=0; ?>
                <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item,$i) ?>
                    <?php $i++; ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
                <div class="clear"><br /></div>
                <div class="paypal-totals">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('totals'); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"><br /></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('details-table');</script>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="clear"><br /></div>
```